# Criterion for a group to be abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group of order $pq$ , where $p,q$ are primes and $p<q$ . Show that if $p \nmid (q-1)$ (i.e  $q \not \equiv 1\mod p )$ then $G$ is abelian.

I was able to use Sylow's theorems to prove that the group is cyclic and hence abelian (Sketch of what I did: the number of $p$-Sylow subgroups is $1$ or $q$  but since $q \not \equiv 1\mod p$ there is one $p$-Sylow subgroup and it is normal , similarly I showed that the number of $q$-Sylow subgroups is $1$ and also normal I then took their direct product, of the sylow subgroups that is, both are cyclic since they are of prime orders I then showed that the multiplication of generators generates the direct product which is isomorphic to $G$ it follows that G is abelian )

Besides the fact that the above proof looks very messy, I'm looking for a proof that does not use any Sylow theorem.

Comment: What do you know about semidirect products?

Comment: @mixedmath I've never heard of them, I just looked them up on Wikipedia. They seem similar to internal direct products but only requiring one of the subgroups to be normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done without Sylow as follows:

By Cauchy's theorem, the group has a subgroup of order $p$ and one of order $q$. If $p < q$ then the subgroup of order $q$ has index $p$ which is the smallest prime dividing the order of the group, so it is normal (see various proofs of this at [Normal subgroup of prime index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164244/normal-subgroup-of-prime-index/)).

Now we know that the group is a semidirect product of $C_p$ with $C_q$ and since there is no non-trivial homomorphism from $C_p$ to $\rm{Aut}(C_q)$, since the latter has order $q-1$ which $p$ does not divide, this semidirect product is in fact direct, and we are done.

Just saw that you were not familiar with semidirect products, so here is a way without them:

We want to show that not only is the subgroup of order $q$ normal, it is in fact central. To see this, let $H$ be the $q$-Sylow subgroup (that normality implies uniqueness for Sylow subgroups is a lot easier to prove than the general theorems. For a generalization with an elementary proof, see [Rotman introduction to theory of groups exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260837/rotman-introduction-to-theory-of-groups-exercise/)).

We know from the N/C theorem that $G/C_G(H)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\rm{Aut}(H)$ But we also know that since $H\leq C_G(H)$ we have that $|G/C_G(H)|$ divides $p$, and since $p$ does not divide the order of $\rm{Aut}(H)$ the only possibility is that $C_G(H) = G$ so $H$ is central.

Now let $K$ be any subgroup of order $p$. Since $|HK| = |G|$ we see that any element of $G$ can be written uniquely as $hk$ with $h\in H$ and $k\in K$ and since $H$ is central, elements of this form commute, so the group is abelian.

Added: The N/C theorem is the following: Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Then $C_G(H)$ is a normal subgroup of $N_G(H)$ and $N_G(H)/C_G(H)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\rm{Aut}(H)$. The proof is by defining a homomorphism from $N_G(H)$ to $\rm{Aut}(H)$ by letting any $g\in N_G(H)$ go to the action on $H$ by conjugation and noting that this homomorphism has exactly $C_G(H)$ as its kernel.

Comment: thank you for the proof, I am actually unfamiliar with most of the theorems besides Cauchy's theorem but you posted sources which is great, I'll understand them and get back to this.

Comment: @user10444 I added a short remark on the N/C theorem.

Answer (score 2):

By Cauchy's Theorem, $G$ contains subgroups of order $p$ and $q$. Let $x,y\in G$ such that $\langle x\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}_p,\langle y\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}_q$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_p\not\leq Aut(\mathbb{Z}_q)$, so $x$ centralises $y$, i.e., $x^{-1}yx=y$, and hence $x,y$ commute. Then $|\langle x,y\rangle|=pq$, and so $G=\langle x,y\rangle$ is abelian.

Comment: Is the derived group the commutator subgroup (the elements of the form $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ )? Also isn't there a missing order in the first case?

Comment: Yes, the derived group is an alternative name for the commutator group. And the missing case you meant $|G'|=pq$?

Comment: @Easy Indeed the case $|G'| = pq$ is the tricky one (showing that it cannot happen, that is), since once you show that the group is not perfect, the rest follows.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, you are right, I have just amended my method.