# if H is a subgroup and N is a normal subgroup is H normal in HN?

Tags: group-theory

The title speaks for itself, I saw something that requires it but I can't seem to prove it, any help is appreciated!

I'm asking because of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148528/question-about-normal-subgroup-and-relatively-prime-index#comment342219_148528) comment which specify that from the second isomorphism theorem we know that $[HK:H]=[K:H\cap K]$ suggesting that $H\triangleleft HK$ when in the question we have that $K\triangleleft G$ and $H\le G$

Comment: Let $G$ be a group with a nonnormal subgroup $H$. Let $N=G$. Then $HN=G$ and $H$ is not normal in $HN$. Are you sure that this is what you want?

Comment: If you pick $N=G$ then it would mean that every subgroup is normal. Which is not true. So, there are plenty of counterexamples. Even with $N$ a proper subgroup of $G$. Try some small examples.

Comment: I'm asking because of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148528/question-about-normal-subgroup-and-relatively-prime-index#comment342219_148528)

Comment: What do you don't understand about the proof? Make that clear to us please, so we can help.

Comment: Edit the link into your question. It is absurd to omit such information when you have it. What part exactly do you think requires this (false) result?

Comment: I think I clarified by your comments I now know that it's false just as I suspected but it's still not clear to me how it "adds up"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me that your core mistake is that you seem to think the 'index of' relation *(denoted by the '[:]')* is only applicable between a group and a *normal* subgroup.  Actually it is applicable between a group and *any* subgroup.